# How to generate unique id of Android device?

Tags: android, delphi, delphi-xe5

I need to use an **unique ID** for an Android app (exm: serial number of device). How do I retrieve the serial number of an Android device or other codes in my app ?

Comment: See also http://android-developers.blogspot.se/2011/03/identifying-app-installations.html  (which is linked to in one of the comments for the duplicate question)

Comment: SEE THE TAGS : DELPHI-XE5 . my question not duplicated in this site. i work in delphi (not java).

Comment: It's not like you're going to have any additional device IDs available to you just because you're writing your application in Delphi. If you're having trouble accessing the Java APIs from your Delphi code, google for _"delphi xe5 android api"_.

Answer (score 0):

Look here https://stackoverflow.com/a/9186943/2007457

"There’s rather useful info here.
It covers five different ID types:

IMEI (only for Android devices with Phone use; needs android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE)

Pseudo-Unique ID (for all Android devices)

Android ID (can be null, can change upon factory reset, can be altered on rooted phone)

WLAN MAC Address string (needs android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE)

BT MAC Address string (devices with Bluetooth, needs android.permission.BLUETOOTH)"

Answer (score 0):

i have created once class and use this in my app see [this](https://gist.github.com/milaptank/25eddae25b59c643eb19)

its create unique ID and generate MD5 message as string of unique  device ID

Comment: SEE THE TAGS : DELPHI-XE5 . my question not duplicated in this site. i work in delphi (not java).